# gulp compile multiple css from multiple sass folders with single command?

Tags: build, sass, gulp

I have the following files structure:

```
themes
  folder1
    -scss
      -style.scss
  folder2
    -scss
      -style.scss
  foldern
    -scss
      -style.scss

  package.json
  gulpfile.js
```

Need Output in this format:

```
themes
  folder1
    -scss
      -style.scss
    css
      -style.css
  folder2
    -scss
      -style.scss
    css
      -style.css
  foldern
    -scss
      -style.scss
    css
      -style.css

  package.json
  gulpfile.js
```

gulpfile.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')

  gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp
      .src('./**/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'uncompressed'
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./**/css'));
  });

  gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('sass', function () {
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  }));

})();
```

When I compiled using above gulpfile then it's creating **/css/folder1/stle.css **/css/folder2/style.css folders in the theme directory. how can I compile in this format? Is there any specific plugin there in gulp for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  // etc.

  // two more plugins
  rename = require('gulp-rename')
  path = require('path');


  gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp
      .src('./**/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'uncompressed'
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))

       // rename the current file's parent directory

      .pipe(rename(function (file) {

        // file.dirname = current folder, your "scss"
        // then get the parent of the current folder, e.g., "folder1", "folder2", etc.
        let parentFolder = path.dirname(file.dirname)

        // set each file's folder to "folder1/css", "folder2/css", etc.
        file.dirname = path.join(parentFolder, 'css');
      }))

      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
  });
```

Comment: This is also creating CSS folder in scss folder.

Comment: It is not doing that for me.  Did you have a stray file around from prior testing?  Try starting from a clean folder and file structure as you presented in your question.

Comment: my srtucture is: scss->base->base.scss, scss->global->global.scss